# Why can't compare two strings in if condition?

Tags: c++

Why can't compare two strings in `if` condition?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string  sexo[20], feminino; 
  feminino = "f";

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
    do {
      cout << endl << "enter your " << i + 1 << "sexo: ";
      cin >> sexo[i];

      if (strcmp(sexo[i], feminino)==0){ // problem in here     
        cout << "that's ok" << endl;
      }

    } while (nome[i] == "0");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: woh woh! Please format this code correctly! Also tell us what you expect this code to do and why it isnt working!

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `strcmp` would show you that the parameters are different types than the arguments you're giving. Looking at documentation for `std::string`, you'll find comparison operators. Any introductory book should cover this as well.

Comment: Part two is, [Start with code that actually compiles!](http://ideone.com/Nj3gh4)

Comment: So your problem statement is, um, "can't". Nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are a few correct ways to compare these strings (in reverse order of preference)

```
if (strcmp(sexo[i].c_str(), feminino.c_str()) == 0) {

if (sexo[i].compare(feminino)) == 0) {

if (sexo[i] == feminino) {
```

Answer (score 10):

You've been reading "tutorials" for C, or "tutorials" for C++ that actually teach you a terrible and outdated mix of C and C++.

The function `strcmp` is from the C Standard Library, and does not operate on the C++ `std::string` type.

To compare two `std::string`s, simply write:

```
if (sexo[i] == feminino) {
```

I find it hard to believe that your C++ book does not teach you this.

Comment: @Ben: It is not "unnecessary". It is _utterly_ crucial if the OP is to understand where she or he has gone wrong here, and learn for next time.

Comment: Reading a good book is crucial, I agree. Saying the OP has been reading terrible tutorials, doesnt help. Saying you find something hard to believe doesnt help. Suggest a *good* tutorial, suggest a *good* book ...

Comment: This is the most correct answer here, honestly, since using strcmp with std::string is unnecessary. (A link to a GOOD tutorial or book on the topic would help, though. They can be hard to find if you don't know what to look for.)

Comment: @Ben: Recommending resources is out of the scope of this answer, nay this _website_. But I insist on firmly steering the OP away from whichever ones gave her or him the notion that `strcmp` was appropriate on a `std::string` in C++. If you read between the lines rather than pretending you can only see the literal in things, you'll see that my final statement is not _actually_ about my "beliefs", but a _strong_ indication that the OP should refer to the C++ book that they haven't bought let alone read yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong compare function. What you are using works with `char *` (it is used in C) but here you have `std::string` so you have to use `std::string::compare()`
Change your code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {


   string  sexo[20], feminino; // problem in here

   feminino = "f";

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      do {
          cout << endl << "enter your " << i + 1 << "sexo: ";
          cin >> sexo[i];

          if (sexo[i].compare(feminito) == 0){
             cout << "that's ok" << endl;
          }

      } while (nome[i] == "0");
   }


return 0;
```

Note that you can also use `sexo[i] == feminito` as you have relational operators for `std::string` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/) for examples)

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `==`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit nothing at all. My edit was on the way. You were faster ^^

Comment: Best to post the whole answer the first time around :)

Comment: Yup, sorry about that :)